# What happens when the length of a string is greater than the length of it's characters?

Tags: c, append, c-strings

```
char matrix_string[1000] = "the";
```

In the code above, is the resulting string "the" followed by a bunch of zeros or garbage values? What should I do if I know that this string will be getting bigger as I will be appending values to it?

Comment: C strings should be null terminated. Your string should be "the\0"

Comment: @LeeTaylor: Literal strings (`"the"`) are automatically nul terminated by the compiler; it is unnecessary to do this manually.

Comment: Ah, yes. It's been a while...

Comment: @GregHewgill so after the nul character is placed by the compiler, the rest of the characters will be set to 0 or be uninitialized as you said below?

Comment: @VanGo: Yes, I'll clarify my answer.

Comment: `matrix_string` is not actually a string; we just call it that for short. `matrix_string` is an array of 1000 characters, whose first 4 characters happen to be a valid string.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you initialize an array with fewer items than the array can hold, the remainder of the array is initialized to zero. Using a string literal as an initializer is no different. When you use a string literal to initialize an array, all of the array elements after the string will be initialized to zero.

The following quote is from the C11 specification, §6.7.9 paragraph 21 (emphasis added)

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there
>   are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a
>   string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there
>   are elements in the array, **the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage
>   duration**.

And this is what §6.7.9 paragraph 10 says about the initialization of objects that have static storage duration

> If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not 
>   initialized explicitly, then:
>
> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
> - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero
>     bits;
> - if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized
>     to zero bits;

So the line

```
char matrix_string[1000] = "the";
```

puts `'t'`,`'h'`,`'e'`,`'\0'` in the first four elements of the array and sets the other 996 elements to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If `matrix_string` is a global variable, then the remainder of the bytes are initialised to zeros.

If `matrix_string` is a local variable, then the remainder of the bytes (after the first four bytes including the trailing nul) are uninitialised.

Comment: I thought the following bytes (after the first 4 bytes) would always be zero, regardless of whether it's global variable or not.

Comment: If you make it `static` the first argument of this answer would apply too, not only global variables. But as it is the remaining `996` bytes are uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

> is the resulting string "the" followed by a bunch of zeros or garbage values?

It will be all zeros (or NULL characters) after "the". You can just check by printf `matrix_string[5]` for example, with different control `%c` (shows nothing) and `%d` (show zero).